# Pulling data into Access from an external API

Tags: ms-access

[Apologies in advance if this has been asked an answered elsewhere.]

I have recently dived into Microsoft Access 2016 to handle a relatively small (but still too big for Excel) database with somewhat sensitive (read should not live on the internet) information. So far so good.

What I would like to do is be able to pull down information from a publicly available API to update a few columns of a table.

Ex:
For each entry in this table take field A and submit it to the web API. 
The API would then return a list of numbers which I then parse and plug into fields B, C, and D.

**QUESTIONS:**

1. Is this even possible inside Access?
2. Where should I look/what should I search for to figure out how to do it?

I would rather not have to pipe it through Excel or some third party service if possible. I am comfortable programming and don't mind picking up a new language but I can't seem to figure out where to start. Any help from "hit the _____ button." to "Searching for _____ will get you started." would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to have Access VBA interact with a web service would be to use a `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP` object like this:

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub WebRequestExample()
    Dim httpReq As Object, response As String
    Set httpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    httpReq.Open "GET", "http://checkip.dyndns.com", False
    httpReq.Send
    response = httpReq.responseText
    Set httpReq = Nothing
    Debug.Print response
End Sub
```

In this case the `response` string contains

```
<html><head><title>Current IP Check</title></head><body>Current IP Address: 192.168.53.49</body></html>
```

If the web service returns a relatively short and straightforward response then you could just parse it yourself.